# Slider image breakpoints on different screen resolutions

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading, redux-framework

I want uploaded image with slides option https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/slides/ on redux-framework have same height and not let slider image to cover all front page if screen resolution gets above mobile,tablets resolution.

So far i tried to resize image (also set static height)to see also some content below slider image on desktop resolutions 960px and above (i want to see some content below front page slider image on desktop resolutions above 960px),but not to slider image to cover all front page.But when i resize image to see some content below slider image on desktop resolutions 960px and above,then slider images are almost not seen on mobile devices anymore,when it gets 480px and below. Images height is only ok on mobile devices,when slider image covers all front page,but not ok when i resize them to see some content below slider image.

Example:I have now like on this website http://preview.themeforest.net/item/neer-construction-business-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/20851072?ref=cirvitis ,when slider image covers all the front page and page content itself are not seen on front page at all,until i scroll down to it,then image height is ok on mobile devices.

But i want like on this website here: https://codex-themes.com/thegem/meta-splash/  header slider image height is ok on front page when it is resized and i see some content below it and have same results on mobile devices view too.

Now i have good results only when slider image covers all front page,then image are seen ok on mobile devices too. But when i resize front page image,then they are almost not seen on mobile devices.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Edited first post,i hope my problem is more clear now. All solutions to fix this problem are welcome.

Comment: Almost found a solution,only thing is,on mobile view full image is shown,but on higher desktop resolution image gets cropped,any way to fix this?  `.wpdf_slider img {
    height: 850px;
}

.wpdf_slider img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}`

Comment: Found solution:                                                                                      
`.wpdf_slider img {
    height: 750px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wpdf_slider img {
    object-fit: none;
    object-position: 70% 0%;
    object-position: 60 0;
}`